# Error while running via virtual directory using Office Interop

Tags: .net, iis-7.5, office-interop, asp.net-4.5

I have used Office Inter op library for converting office docs to PDF. I am getting the PDF well if i run through Visual Studio, but i am getting the following error while running via virtual directory.

**Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))**

Please reply if anybody have the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Office Interop library you are referencing isn't on your server.  You need to:

1) Make sure the server has Office, since it is required for interop.

2) Copy the libraries you are referencing to the proper location on the server.